# Roster program for java

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I have a question on how to solve this program. I have done the outline of this but I need help completing it. Thank you everyone for input!

**Problem.**

An object of class `Roster` represents a particular section of a course. A roster has an array of `students`, an `int numStudents`, that says how many students there are in the section, an `int stopPoint` that gives the maximum number of students that may be in the section, and a `course` that says which course this roster is a section of.

Note that the students are not in any particular order in the array, but they will be in the first `numStudents` elements of the array.

**Code:**

```
public class Roster {
    Student [ ] students;
    int numStudents;
    int stopPoint;
    Course course;

    /**
     * The constructor for this class.
     * Initialize this roster so that it is empty, i.e., holds no students,
     *  but so that it can hold up to stopPoint students
     *   and so that it has the given stop point and course
     */
    public Roster(int stopPoint, Course course){
    this.stopPoint = stopPoint;
    this.course = course;
    this.students = new Student [stopPoint];
    }

    /**
     * toString is a method every class has.  It returns a string 
     * that represents the object for printing
     */
    public String toString( ){
    String res = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < numStudents; j++){
        res = res + "\n" + students[j].toString();
    }
    return course + " " + numStudents + "/" + stopPoint+res;
    }

    /**
     * isFull returns true if and only if the number of students in it is 
     *   at the stopPoint
     */
    public boolean isFull( ){
    return false;   // replace this line with your code
    }

    /**
     * add given student to this roster
     * if student already on roster or numStudents already == stopPoint, 
     *   do not change roster and return false
     * worst case O(1) - add the new Student at the end of the array
     * @return true if successful, else false
     */
    public boolean addStudent(Student student){

    return false; // replace this line with your code

    }


    /**
     * returns true if and only if the student is on this roster.
     */
    public boolean findStudent(Student student){

    return false; // replace this line with your code

    }

    /**
     * Remove given student from this roster. 
     * If student is not on this roster do not change roster and return           false
     * @return true if successful, else false
     */
    public boolean dropStudent(Student student){

    return false; // replace this line with your code

    }

}
```

Comment: and what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a List instead of an array to save the students, and then the rest of the methods that you have would simply delegate to this list.

```
public Roster(int stopPoint, Course course){
this.stopPoint = stopPoint;
this.course = course;
this.students = new ArrayList<Students>(stopPoint);
}


public String toString( ){
String res = "";
for(Student s: students){
    res = res + "\n" + s.toString();
}
return course + " " + numStudents + "/" + stopPoint+res;
}


public boolean isFull( ){
return students.size() == stopPoint;
}


public boolean addStudent(Student student){
if(!student.contains(student) && !isFull()){
    students.add(student);
    return true;    
}
    return false;

}

public boolean findStudent(Student student){
return students.contains(student);
}

public boolean dropStudent(Student student){
return students.remove(student); 
}
```